# How to configure Qt to include a class from another project (not a static library)?

Tags: c++, qt, include, unresolved-external

I would like to use a class from one Qt project (A) in another (B). I am able to successfully include the .h file from A in B, and build project B. However, when I try to create an object declared in the .h file in B, I get a link error (Unresolved External Symbol). Can I do what I am trying to do, and if so how? I have tried using include() in my B.pro file, but get compile errors. The link error is the farthest I have gotten (with no changes to my .pro file).

In B's main.cpp file I have:
    #include "../A/testymctestface.h"

In the main I try to create an object of the included class:

```
TestyMcTestFace test;
```

This is when I get the link error.

testymctestface.h contains:

```
class TestyMcTestFace{
public:
    TestyMcTestFace();
};
```

testymctestface.cpp contains:

```
#include "testymctestface.h"

TestyMcTestFace::TestyMcTestFace(){

}
```

Comment: You need to add the .cpp into the second project as well, not just the header file (.h).

Comment: @johnelemans do you mean in the SOURCES part of the .pro file? If I do that I get this error...

:-1: warning: C:/Users/Pack/Documents/Projects/TestImport/main.cpp conflicts with C:/Users/Pack/Documents/Projects/DataScatter/main.cpp

Comment: Not all the sources, just the class that you wish to use. (like testyMcTestFace.cpp in your example)

Comment: That's all I'm doing.. 
My pro file...

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp \
    scattermodifier.cpp \
    KMeans.cpp \
    Point.cpp \
    ../TestImport/testymctestface.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h \
    scattermodifier.h \
    KMeans.h \
    Point.h \
    ../TestImport/testymctestface.h

Comment: Well, that should work. You don't have testImport/main.cpp in there, so it should not be possible to create the conflict. Run qmake.

Comment: That's what gives me the error :(

Comment: Oh! Tricky. I had to CLEAN and then run qmake. Thanks for your help..